# meteor.js Alternative package for:”yogiben: notifications”, and “telescope: notifications”

Tags: javascript, meteor

Seeking an alternative package for packages:

1.yogiben: notifications

During the Installation of the package for version 1.2.1, is replaced Meteor error:

```
"While Selecting package versions:
error: No version of less satisfies all constraints: @ 1.0.11, @ = 2.5.1
Constraints on package "less":
* Less@1.0.11 <- top level
* Less@=2.5.1 <- top level "
```

2.telescope: notifications

During the Installation of the package for version 1.2.1, is replaced Meteor error:

```
"W20160121-13: 43: 53.585 (0) (stderr) ReferenceError: Users is not defined
W20160121-13: 43: 53.586 (0)? (Stderr) at lib / settings.js: 509: 13
W20160121-13: 43: 53.586 (0)? (Stderr) at /vagrant/meteor/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:249:5 "
```